# How can I make my iptables rules perist after reboot on CENTOS 7

Tags: centos, networking, iptables

iptables-save > /etc/iptables.ruleset
I run this and it doesnt save after reboot

please give  me a soultion

Answer (score 0):

CentOS uses a [different file and location](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/security_guide/sec-setting_and_controlling_ip_sets_using_iptables). Linux distros have different ways of doing certain things.

`/etc/sysconfig/iptables`

Then there's `firewalld` which works totally differently and your iptables rules might not even apply.